# Excel IF Cell = This then Copy more than one column

Tags: excel

I have an excel IF statement that says IF cell AB1=5 Then AC1 but wondering how to copy multiple columns at the same time. IF AB1=5 then copy AC1:AE1. So if AB1=5 Then I want all three cells copied to AC1,AD1,AE1.

Any help is appreciated. THanks!

Comment: What 3 cells do you want copied?

Comment: AC1,AD1, and AE1. Sheet2

Comment: And put in different cells?

Comment: @ScottCraner: Yes, put in different cells. THanks

Comment: Each cell will have its own formula.  Put `=IF($AB1 = 5,AC1,"")` in the first cell.  Copy/Drag over three columns, `AC1` will change to the next column automatically.

Answer (score 0):

What about just putting this formula in each cell on sheet2?

```
=IF(Sheet1!AB1=5,Sheet1!AB1,"")
```